# Recess framework: Why am I getting a resource not found error when the file exists?

Tags: php, url-routing, recess

I'm thinking of using the [Recess Framework](http://www.recessframework.org/) which I downloaded as-is and followed the instructions studiously.

I'm using it with PHP (which is not the issue) and I seem to have it up and running... however I suspected something was slightly wrong with the pages being served (they did not contain the expected logos) so I inspected the code only to find out that the frameworks javascript and CSS files were "resource not found".

Incidentally the files exist at the path specified, and it's not a question that permissions are not set correctly - I checked that too.

But... I'm new to using "routing" through URLs as part of a MVC style and wondered if basically it has something to do with that.

If you download the framework, you'll find that the css and javascript files that make things look pretty, and activate certain parts of the framework toolset exists at the path:

```
http://localhost/yourRecessFolderName/index.php/recess/recess/apps/tools/public/js/shCore.js
```

but I get the dreaded 404 resource not found and this is preventing recess tools from working properly.

1) Has any body else had this or a similar problem?
2) What are the likely causes - help by pointing me in the right direction, unless you know the answer of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Recess v0.2, there is an .htaccess file in /apps that prevents direct access to children. You'd need to modify the .htaccess or configure something custom in mod_rewrite to allow the public folders under apps to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seemed to fix it by downloading the most recent ("latest edge") version of the Recess framework from https://github.com/recess/recess

Everything seems to work fine now... hmm 0.o

Answer (score 0):

When pass from Development to Production, the Recess Framework use a Cache for accelerate access to site. Is possible, in your case, that the cache content is wrong.

I suggest you access path **/your/recess/path/data/temp** and remove the files **recess.php** and **sqlite-cache.db** and try again.

I hope this help you.